Creating responsive SVG shapes with consistent stroke width and rounded corners
I'm working on a project where I need to create SVG shapes with strokes that are responsive to their parent container size. I want these shapes to always fill the width and height of their parent container, and I also want to position them absolutely within the parent. Additionally, I need to add stroke colors to these shapes.
One issue I'm encountering is that the stroke width seems inconsistent. Sometimes, even when I set the stroke width to 1px, it appears much thicker, possibly 10px or more, making the shapes look distorted.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
I added here 1px stroke width, but I think it's getting much. Also top, bottom and left, right stroke width are getting different size though I added 1px for each side. Also how can I add 5px border radius to this path


body {
   padding: 100px 20px;
}


.parent-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: black;
    clip-path: polygon(
      0% 0%,
      95% 0%,
      100% 20%,
      100% 100%,
      5% 100%,
      0% 80%,
      0% 0%
    );
    position: relative;
}


.cta-stroke {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}

path {
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke: red;
}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>svg shapes</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="parent-container">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" preserveAspectRatio="none" 
  class="cta-stroke">
  <path d="M0 0  L95 0  L100 20 L100 100 L5 100 L0 80 L0 0 Z" />
 </svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>



How can I achieve responsiveness and absolute positioning of SVG shapes with strokes that adapt to the size of their parent container while ensuring consistent stroke width? Also, how can I add rounded corners to the shapes? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

SVG syntax note: there are no namespaces in HTML5, so even though you need that namespace if you're creating an SVG document (i.e. an .svgflavoured XML file, or a new SVG XML node created using document.createElementNS), you should not add a namespace to <svg> tags that are part of an HTML5 document.

(also note that clip-path lets you use specify an SVG path, letting you specify the same thing that you use in your SVG, which usually makes a lot more sense than having an SVG path but a polygon clipping path)

Tip number 7 from this article on the topic of responsive SVGs may be helpful:

By default, SVG scales everything with the viewport, including stroke
thickness. Usually this works out fine, but in some cases – diagrams
and strokes applied as effects on the outside of text in particular –
you may want to keep strokes the same thickness, no matter what the
size of the drawing. This is the domain of the little-known
vector-effect property, which can be applied as a presentation
attribute or in CSS.

vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;

Here is the relevant text from the MDN documentation for this property value:

This value modifies the way an object is stroked. Normally stroking
involves calculating stroke outline of the shape's path in current
user coordinate system and filling that outline with the stroke paint
(color or gradient). The resulting visual effect of this value is that
the stroke width is not dependent on the transformations of the
element (including non-uniform scaling and shear transformations) and
zoom level.

Browser support is green across the board.
The snippet below demonstrates the effect of this property. The SVG contains a square 20 pixels in size, styled with a 1 pixel red border. The copy on the left scales in the default manner, so the border scales in proportion with the shape. The copy on the right scales with vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke set.



body {
  background: #888;
  margin: 1em;
}

.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

svg rect {
  fill: pink;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

svg:last-child rect {
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}
<div class="d1">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 22 22">
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="20" height="20"/>
  </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 22 22">
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="20" height="20"/>
  </svg>
  
</div>



After running the snippet, use the full page link to test the responsive behaviour.
Rounded corners
As for this part of your question, you can round the corners of certain shapes, for example with a <rect> you can specify the roundness of the corners with the rx and ry properties. You cannot round a <path>, though, because a path by nature contains precise curvature information. You would think that <polygon> and <polyline> would provide some kind of corner-rounding property, but unfortunately they do not. Here is some further reading on rounded corners in SVG.

Once you have absorbed the information I provided relating to rounded corners, I am going to edit both your question and my answer to remove anything related to rounded corners. A “question” on Stack Overflow needs to contain exactly one question, whereas yours contains two. The primary question is about scaling, so we’ll keep that part.

Many many thanks sir. It helps me a lot. I got my solution. Can you please tell me a simple way to add rounded corners to the path element.

My advice would be to edit the path yourself use an SVG editing tool such as Boxy SVG. Another option which may work is to use a Javascript library to do the job for you.
